# Flutter Carousel null safety

Tags: flutter, carousel

I want to know how I can perform null safety on carousel slider receiving data from API.
Because anytime I run it the carousel does work but I get the getter length was called on a null first.

```
CarouselSlider(
                    autoPlay: true,
                    pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 5),
                    height: 100,
                    items: <Widget>[
                      for(var i=0; i<dashDataRandomCategories.length; i++)
                        Container(
                          margin:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 20.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  dashDataRandomCategories[i]
                                  ['product_cat_image']),
                              //image: NetworkImage(image[i]),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            // border:
                            //     Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ]
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a best solution, but give you a clear Idea.
you have to apply a condition.
when data is from API is coming, `dashDataRandomCategories` is null that time.
suppose , the `CarouselSlider` is in column.when  `dashDataRandomCategories` is loading, you can show a place holder, a `Container()` or a shimmer maybe, when the data is loaded, now you can show the slider!

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(),
    dashDataRandomCategories.length == null ? Container(child: Text("Data is Loading")) : CarouselSlider(
                autoPlay: true,
                pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 5),
                height: 100,
                items: <Widget>[
                  for(var i=0; i<dashDataRandomCategories.length; i++)
                    Container(
                      margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 20.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              dashDataRandomCategories[i]
                              ['product_cat_image']),
                          //image: NetworkImage(image[i]),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        // border:
                        //     Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                ]
              ),Container()]
```